# Shading/ environment on unreal engine 5

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5

Someone know how to do this shading / post processing like this picture on unreal engine 5 please ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYUDD.jpg)

thank you

nothing for the moment

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! This type of question isn't really related to code and would be better suited for the Unreal Engine forums or the Unreal Slackers discord

Answer (score 0):

Look using unreal engine 5 ray traced lighting you can get the lighting effect and for that look you need low poly stylized texture , with both of these things you can achieve it for sure .